# Powershell web scraping IE drop down not updating values

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer, scripting, screen-scraping

I'm currently trying to develop a script in PowerShell that opens Internet Explorer, changes two drop down values (which updates a tables values), then scrape the table to a CSV file preferably.

By the way, the site has a static URL, changing the drop down doesn't change the URL:(

I can Get IE to open and change the two drop down values, but the table is not updating its values after this...
I think it is something to do with the site code where it shows the option for this dropdown as:

```
<select id="pricing-display-by-dropdown" 
onchange="$('html').trigger('rate.changed', this.value)">
 <option value="hour">Hour</option>
 <option value="month">Month</option>
</select>
```

So basically what I have is this so far, and it will change the region and pricing, but won't update the table, maybe have to fire the trigger above somehow?:

```
$url = "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/" 
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy() -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 6000 }

$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("region-selector").value = "europe-north"

$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("pricing-display-by-dropdown").value = "month"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i'm new to PowerShell, and stackoverflow, so excuse any silly stuff

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("pricing-display-by-dropdown").fireEvent("onchange")
```